# Non-english characters in python dictionary not printed correctly

Tags: python, json, dictionary, unicode, utf-8

ok, this first,yes I have read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Still I have problems understanding why:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
a='ööö'
b='ääß'

print a+' '+b
>>>ööö ääß

print {'a':a,'b':b}
>>>{'a': '\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb6', 'b': '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa4\xc3\x9f'}
```

Can someone assist in how to simply have the output like

```
print {'a':a,'b':b}
    >>>{'a': 'ööö', 'b': 'ääß'}
```

I tried every combination of unicode(a), a.encode('utf-8'), unicode(a).encode('utf-8') and the likes, no avail.

Feeling stupid.

Would really appreciate if someone could explain this foor noobs, with full examples.l

Thanks a lot!

Comment: With `print`-ing a dictionary you will get a representation as near to the data as possible. In the given cast that is the encoded string. For output used to be read by humans you should iterate over the dict and print the keys and values separately. Also if you are using Python 2 you should check if a `u` before your strings is needed.

Comment: Ah yeah! thanks! I figured it now. by acessing the values via key it works

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {'a': unicode('ööö', 'utf-8'), 'b': unicode('ääß', 'utf-8')}
>>> print repr(d).decode("unicode-escape")
{'a': u'ööö', 'b': u'ääß'}
```